# How to use a "long" color?

Tags: java, android, colors, android-8.0-oreo

Android API 26 introduces new ways to handle a [color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html):

> Color longs are a representation introduced in Android O to store
>   colors in different color spaces, with more precision than color ints.

Now we can use new color spaces, like this:

```
    long longGreenColor = Color.pack(0.0f, 3.1415f, 0.0f, 1.0f, ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.LINEAR_EXTENDED_SRGB));
```

Nice, a long color. Now what?

- Can **NOT** be used in `android.graphics.Canvas`
- Can **NOT** be used in `android.graphics.Paint`
- Can **NOT** be used in `android.graphics.Bitmap`

## How I am supposed to use a long color when drawing?

For example:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(20, 20, Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16, true, ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.LINEAR_EXTENDED_SRGB));
    long longColor = Color.pack(0.0f, 3.1415f, 0.0f, 1.0f, ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.LINEAR_EXTENDED_SRGB));

    bitmap.eraseColor(longColor);//ERROR
    bitmap.eraseColor(Color.toArgb(longColor));//BAD!
    bitmap.eraseColor((int) longColor);//WRONG!!!

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(longColor);//ERROR

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawPoint(1, 1, paint);
```

Comment: What do these "ERROR", "WRONG", "BAD" comments mean? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash? Does it give wrong results (if yes, then what exactly?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a long ( not *ColorLong* :D ) time since the question, but did you scroll down further on the documentation?...

There is a [dedicated section in `Color`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#color-longs) about such colors.

For instance you can use the static method [`Color.valueOf(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#valueOf(long)) to convert from `long` to `Color` or just use the non-static method [`Paint.setColor(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColor(long)) to use it directly.

You can create a color with type `long` with the static [`Color.pack(float, float, float)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#pack(float,%20float,%20float)) for example. That's in the [Encoding section](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#encoding_1).

In the [Decoding section](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#decoding_1) it says you may use a method such as the static [`Color.alpha(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#alpha(long)) to obtain a `long` color's component (*alpha* component in this case).

Hope that helps.

Comment: To use Paint.setColor(LongColor) we need API level 29, so we need to use Android 10.  When I asked this question, the API level was at 26. **Upgrade to Android 10, that is the answer.**

Comment: Ok. I tried loading API level 26 in the webpage but it wouldn't load for some reason. Where those methods missing from API 26? Was this documentation missing from API 26? Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Yes, Android 8 didn't. :(

Answer (score -1):

Colors instances are immutable and can be created using one of the various valueOf methods. For instance:

```
// sRGB
 Color opaqueRed = Color.valueOf(0xffff0000); // from a color int
 Color translucentRed = Color.valueOf(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);

 // Wide gamut color
 @ColorLong long p3 = pack(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, colorSpaceP3);
 Color opaqueYellow = Color.valueOf(p3); // from a color long

 // CIE L*a*b* color space
 ColorSpace lab = ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.LAB);
 Color green = Color.valueOf(100.0f, -128.0f, 128.0f, 1.0f, lab);
```

[More info: https://developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Comment: This is not an answer. Long color is not able to be used in Canvas indeed.